# Firestore Emulator: Simulate external update

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore snapshot listeners should not react to local database changes, so I filter for `hasPendingWrites`.

For testing purposes: Is there a way to simulate an external data change without manually changing data in my Firestore Emulator?
When I call `updateDoc` in my tests, the `hasPendingWrites` flag is set and my snaphot listeners don't fire.

Disabling the `hasPendingWrites` in the filters is not an option (since there are many other local database updates that should be ignored in the tests).

Comment: Sure, just write a standalone program to update a document.  You can use the Firebase Admin SDK or one of the GCP Firestore SDKs for that.

Comment: OK. Thank you. This sounds like a lot of work to wire up, for just my two unit tests.

Comment: I would call it pretty normal for integration tests like you're doing here.  Integration tests very often require some amount of orchestration to get all the various components of the system ready to go.